# IOError on django admin page

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm getting the following cryptic error message on the Django admin page.  Does anyone think they know what went wrong?

If it helps at all (this could be unrelated) the image field seems to be rejecting everything as corrupt or not an image.

```
   Request Method:  GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/cozcus/event/
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
(2, 'No such file or directory')
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py in _open, line 159
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/morgan/Documents/programming/django/cozycuisine',
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/simplegeo-3.0.115-py2.6.egg',
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/simplejson-2.1.6-py2.6.egg',
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/ipaddr-2.1.9-py2.6.egg',
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/oauth2-1.5.170-py2.6.egg',
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/httplib2-0.7.1-py2.6.egg',
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg',
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pyfacebook-1.0a2-py2.6.egg',
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.0.1-py2.6.egg',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages',
'/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-        unicode']
 Server time:   Mon, 18 Jul 2011 13:40:37 -0500
```

Below I have my models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_key = models.CharField(max_length = 10, unique = True) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    food_type = models.CharField(max_length = 400)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True)
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'host')
    guests = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'guest')
    image = models.ImageField(height_field = 'image_height', width_field = 'image_width', upload_to =                 '~/documents/programming/django/cozycuisine/media', blank = True, null = True)
    image_height = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    image_width = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)        

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

`

Comment: It seems as if django can't find a specific file or directory. Maybe from a missing image from the image ImageField?

Answer (score 0):

'~/documents/programming/django/cozycuisine/media'

I don't think that you can use the `~`, try a full absolute path and see what happens.